# Sending data from template to Django views via button

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create a delete button in my template:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value={{ instance.name }}> Delete </button>
```

And I want this button to submit that data in my views.py :

```
instance_client = compute_v1.InstancesClient()
if request.method == "POST":
        instance = request.POST['data']
        instance_client.delete(project='xxx', zone='xxx', instance=HERE_I_WANT_THE_DATA)
```

It's a script that will delete an instance from gcloud.
But I don't know exactly how to deliver the data from the template to views.py.
I'm using Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understand your question.

Template

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_function' item.id %}" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Cancel</a>
 <input class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Views

```
def deleteFunction(request, pk):
 item = Model.objects.get(id=pk)
 if request.method == "POST":
  item.delete()
  return redirect('/')
```

url

```
path('delete_function/<str:pk>', views.deleteFunction, name='delete_function')
```

Comment: Hey vignesh ! thanks for your answer.
But I get the error that Model is not defined on views.py .

Comment: From template you are sending deleting instance name or id (primary key), so you need to receive that in your post method, fetch that instance using that id or name and delete that instance, remove the line `item = Model.objects.get(id=pk)` and write your instance fetch there and proceed to delete

Comment: I'm kind of new to Django. Can you help to write the fetch there ? Sorry to bug you.